# Create a payment method after receiving a bank token with financial connection using Stripe API

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm attempting to create a payment method to save for future use per the stripe documentation. I was able to create a financial session and pass the client secret to the frontend and receive a bank token. Now I will like to use the token to create a payment method where customers can do an inbound transfer to their financial account. Has anyone with experience with Stripe able to achieve this.

I want to avoid the collecting bank information such as routing number and account number and rather leverage the Oauth integration stripe has with collecting bank information. I would appreciate any feedback to anyone who's familiar with stripe or has done this.

Comment: is there any specific reason why you don't use the SetupIntent to directly create a PaymentMethod instead?

Comment: @alex I was wondering if I could use the bank token to create a payment method but from the docs I see this is not intended and rather use a setup intent.